# Push Notifications on Windows Desktop Apps

Tags: windows, flutter, push-notification, wns

we are currently writing an Cross-Plattform Application for Android, iOS and Desktop / Windows with Flutter.

Our Application relies on Push Notifications to trigger actions in our application, which works perfectly fine on Android and iOS. On Windows we ship our application with an InnoSetup-Installer as an .exe. Is it possible to use the Microsoft Service (WNS) for sending Push Notifications to our application? Or is this only possible for Windows Store Applications?

Thank you and best regards

Langohr

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do server push notifications to a Flutter Windows app?

Comment: No, we did not follow the approach.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a plugin https://pub.dev/packages/quick_notify for that. The repo seems to be archived, though. So not sure about it. It does support Windows notifications.

Comment: It looks like it is only supporting local notifications and not to push them from a server.

Comment: They opened another repo https://github.com/woodemi/quick.flutter/tree/master/packages/quick_notify

Comment: Has anyone come across a way to do server push notifications in a Windows Flutter app?